# Accept-Control-Allow-Origin to return Wildcard always

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I want my CORS settings to always return **Accept-Control-Allow-Origin ***
I am not using Spring security for those request so there is no chance of Spring Security manipulating my Cors configuration.
Currently whatever is passed in Request-Header Origin is exactly getting copied in the response header Accept-Control-Allow-Origin

Example :
Origin : test.com

Output 
Accept-Control-Allow-Origin : test.com

Here is my code

```java
 public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "HEAD", "POST")
                .allowedHeaders("Accept", "Accept-Language", "Content-Language", "Content-Type")
                .exposedHeaders("Allow", "Vary", "Link", "ETag")
                .maxAge(600);
    }
```

How do i fix the issue to always return **Accept-Control-Allow-Origin ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by declaring a filter which will add/update header value in the response

```
    @Component
public class HeaderFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    httpResponse.setHeader("Accept-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this. Thank you

Comment: Even though I include it as a component, it shows that the class is never used. Am I missing something ??

Comment: It will get automatically triggered at runtime. If you using IDE to check whether the class is used, then it will always show that its not used, because it cannot find any reference of it being invoked at runtime. The filter will get registered in runtime

Comment: Thank you had to add this //@WebFilter(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = { "/*" })
and it is working fine now :) Thank you